# How do I style DIVs inside a checkbox label based on if it is checked or not?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, checkbox

In my css I have .interest_selected_icon set as display:none. How to I set a different CSS style if its checkbox is selected?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="people" name="chk_group[]" value="people">
<label class="interest_select" for="people">
    <div class="interest_wrapper">
        People
        <span class="interest_selected_icon">
            selected
        </span>
    </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery, you can do this entirely in CSS:

```
<style>
    .interest_selected_icon {
        display:none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked + .interest_select .interest_selected_icon {
        display:block;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
color:#ccc;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I would also mention that the requires the `label` to be the immediate/ajacent sibling to the check box. The general sibling selector `~` would probably be more robust for basic DOM changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the related `.interest_select` div via DOM traversal on the click event of the checkbox, something like this:

```
$('#people').change(function() {
    var $icon = $(this).next('label').find('.interest_selected_icon')
    $icon[$(this).is(':checked') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/upxgqkon/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery script, which will be called on every change of your checkbox

```
$('#people').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // set style when checkbox is checked
    }else{
       // set style when is not checked
    }
});
```